# Moment.js(moment().format()) is not working in replace of Date.now

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema, momentjs

I am recieving this error when to cast date time with moment js:

> CastError: Cast to date failed for value "Oct 11th 19, 23:57"

at path "date". **Date.now** works, but I want to format it how it is shown below. Any solutions?

```
let User = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: moment().format("MMM Do YY, HH:mm")
    }
});
```

Comment: **moment().format("MMM Do YY, HH:mm")** is not a valid date format according to the MongoDB table column datatype. If you want to insert custom date format, you have to change the column data type to string and it works fine because it is not valid date format to insert in the table.

Answer (score 0):

the function `moment().format("MMM Do YY, HH:mm")` returns a string then you should pass to `type` field the parameter `String`

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [Mongo documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/dates.html) you can see what the date format is. This is a rule defined by Mongo for its users.

Mongoose will cast the value to a native JavaScript date using the [Date() constructor.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax)

It's like you want to store a string in a variable with a number format. The compiler does not allow it. That's perfectly true. In my opinion you should change your model and save your desired date in string format.

```
let User = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: String,
        default: moment().format("MMM Do YY, HH:mm")
    },
    currentDate: { // format is ok with Date in javaScript
        type: date,
        default: date.Now()
    }
});
```

Comment: That is the wrong way to input it, it should be Date.now. But also, why are my dates(hours:minutes) not functioning properly? It seems to keep staying at "17:11" even though I am inputing data after that?

Comment: I think it might be because when I input the date, it saves it in the db, then when the client inputs something new again it looks for that date in the db and retrieves it and uses that one?

Comment: No! You have a variable whose type is date. And you have to keep the date you save to the standard of the date defined in that language. Now with this command you have a date but it is not the same format as defined in Mongo and does not accept it for registration. So it's best to consider that string (your own date) for a standard date as well as a date variable and save it.